# How to set description and link for hyperlink field on NewForm with jquery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm not seeing a clear answer on this after browsing through other answers. Closest I found was this, but doesn't work after fiddling with it for a while. I already have some jquery filling in textboxes, would like to keep going with that.

```
var urlValue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();

urlValue.set_url("http://www.example.com");

urlValue.set_description("test link");

myItem.set_item("TestURL", urlValue);
```

also tried playing with this:

```
$("input[title='Item Path']").eq(1).val("link description");

$('input[id^="ItemPath"]').eq(1).val('link description');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
$("input[id^='testlink']").eq(0).val("http://www,google.com");

$("input[id^='testlink']").eq(1).val("description here");
```